# Azure AD B2C Web Forms examples?

Tags: .net, azure, web, azure-ad-b2c

With the Azure AD B2C public preview out now there are plenty of examples of creating and openID connection through an MVC application, however when I try to mimic the request building method in a Web Forms application it doesn't form the request correctly. Is there an example anywhere as to how to authenticate your Web Forms application to Azure AD B2C?

Comment: I found the solution myself. The gitHub examples have updated packages that were not up to date in Visual Studio 2013 template. Once I went to the NuGet package manager and selected updates, then Update All, republished. I am getting authentication to Azure AD B2C with Web Forms application.

Comment: Were you able to do headless authentication for your web forms project or did you have to use the MS login screen?

Comment: Would you mind sharing a link to the examples you found? I've only been able to find stuff for MVC